# Vagrant Berkshelf could not find the 'berks' executable in your PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, berkshelf, chefdk

I have installed vagrant 1.9.5 and chefdk 2.0.28 in windows
Also added D:\opscode\chefdk\bin\ in path.

But when I tries to run 'vagrant up' command, I get following error.

```
Bringing machine 'project' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

Vagrant Berkshelf could not find the 'berks' executable in your PATH.

Please download and install the latest version of the ChefDK from:

https://downloads.getchef.com/chef-dk

and follow the installation instructions. Do not forget to add the ChefDK to your PATH.
```

I also tried to add different path like D:\opscode\chefdk\, D:\opscode\chefdk\bin\berks, /opt/chefdk/bin, but error remains same.

Comment: Did you reload your console by closing it and restarting it? Can you check that `berks` is in your PATH? (you should be able to see the bin path when you do `where berks` but I am not sure it will work since I am not a Windows CLI pro)

Comment: yes, I restarted console and berks is in path.